# Wordpress menu and footer load slow

Tags: wordpress, menu, loading

i would like to ask about issue i have if someone had simmilar or same problem.

I have pretty old wordpress website, which start to get buggy after a time. When i'm logged in as admin the web is working perfect.
But when i am visiting the page without logging in, the menu footer and some images is loading too long, like 2 minutes or more, when u click on some of the pages in menu, u have to wait the menu to appear.

I have tried deactivate plugins and cleaned cache, now i amm migrating whole web on my hosting to test if the issue is not in client's hosting.

Comment: Update your theme and wordpress.

Comment: i updated wordpress , plugins, but the theme is not making new updates, i tried migrate the website on my secure hosting, and the webpage work correctly, can it be problem in a old hosting provider? My client is using super old company for hosting(atlantis.sk)

Comment: weird thing is, when i am logged as admin it's working also on the old hosting, but when i log out, menu is loading too long, also some images and plugins

Comment: Check you console and network activity after login in and without login. Check if any errors you find which is not supposed to occur and broken links or js errors after login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in wp super cache plugin, maybe wrong settings or just wrong version.

Avoid some special settings in this plugin.
Solved, close.